# SQL database log in - IF statement to go to 2 different pages depending on the output

Tags: vb.net, authentication, sql-server-2012

I have created a log in page that retrieves data from my SQL database to allow the user to log in. I have also made it case sensitive and added a bit to terminate the app when the user enters incorrect log in details more than 3 times.

However, I have got one table for CompanyA and one table for CompanyB; I want to select data out of both of these tables and allow the user to log in.

I also want CompanyA to go to Page1 and CompanyB to go to Page2.

Here is the original code that just selects from one table and goes to one page; I want to try and adapt this code to answer my above question; any ideas?

```
    Try
        Dim objconnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Cara\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Online Portal Solutions\Online Portal Solutions\Online Portal Solutions Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        objconnection.Open()
        Dim SelectStmt As String = "SELECT * FROM [ACustomerLogIn] WHERE Username='" & txt_cusername.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Password='" & txt_cpassword.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS ;"
        Dim objcommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SelectStmt, objconnection)
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = objcommand.ExecuteReader

        If reader.Read Then
            If txt_cpassword.Text <> reader("Password").ToString And txt_cusername.Text <> reader("Username").ToString Then
                frm_2custhome.Show()
                Me.Hide()
                txt_cusername.Clear()
                txt_cpassword.Clear()
            End If
        Else
            Static count As Integer = 0
            Dim prompt As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Invaild Username or Password.", "Login Error",
                                                         MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            Select Case prompt
                Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry
                    txt_cusername.Text = ""
                    txt_cpassword.Text = ""
                    count += 1
                    If count = 3 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("High value of failed login attempts." & vbCrLf & "Application will be terminated for security reasons.", "Error",
                                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
                        End
                    End If
                Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
                    Application.Exit()
            End Select
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Comment: Never use `End`, stick with `Application.Exit`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have fixed it. I have posted my code below in case it helps someone else.

```
    Try
        Dim objconnection1 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Cara\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Online Portal Solutions\Online Portal Solutions\Online Portal Solutions Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        objconnection1.Open()
        Dim SelectStmt1 As String = "SELECT * FROM [AJkpLogIn] WHERE Username='" & txt_husername.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Password='" & txt_hpassword.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS ;"
        Dim objcommand1 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SelectStmt1, objconnection1)
        Dim reader1 As SqlDataReader = objcommand1.ExecuteReader

        Dim objconnection2 As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Cara\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Online Portal Solutions\Online Portal Solutions\Online Portal Solutions Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True")
        objconnection2.Open()
        Dim SelectStmt2 As String = "SELECT * FROM [AClarkeLogIn] WHERE Username='" & txt_husername.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Password='" & txt_hpassword.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS ;"
        Dim objcommand2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(SelectStmt2, objconnection2)
        Dim reader2 As SqlDataReader = objcommand2.ExecuteReader

        If reader1.Read Then
            If txt_hpassword.Text <> reader1("Password").ToString And txt_husername.Text <> reader1("Username").ToString Then
                frm_Rhauljkphome.Show()
                Me.Hide()
                txt_husername.Clear()
                txt_hpassword.Clear()
            End If

        ElseIf reader2.Read Then
            If txt_hpassword.Text <> reader2("Password").ToString And txt_husername.Text <> reader2("Username").ToString Then
                frm_Shaulclarkehome.Show()
                Me.Hide()
                txt_husername.Clear()
                txt_hpassword.Clear()
            End If

        Else
            Static count1 As Integer = 0
            Dim prompt1 As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Invaild Username or Password.", "Login Error",
                                                         MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
            Select Case prompt1
                Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry
                    txt_husername.Text = ""
                    txt_hpassword.Text = ""
                    count1 += 1
                    If count1 = 3 Then
                        MessageBox.Show("High value of failed login attempts." & vbCrLf & "Application will be terminated for security reasons.", "Error",
                                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
                        End
                    End If
                Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
                    Application.Exit()
            End Select
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as selecting from the two source tables in one fell swoop, you could do something like this.  Use a UNION, combine the two sources, only pull the columns you really need (which is a good idea for most select queries) and use a static field with each sub-select to indicate which table it came from:

```
SELECT * FROM (select 'A' AS SourceTable, UserID, Username, Password 
    FROM ACustomerLogIn
UNION
SELECT 'B' AS SourceTable, UserID, Username, Password 
    FROM BCustomerLogIn) as CombinedTables
WHERE Username = 'myusername' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
AND Password = 'mypassword' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Use the 'SourceTable' value (or whatever you choose to name the table-discrimination field) to determine which form to which the user is next sent:

```
        If txt_cpassword.Text <> reader("Password").ToString And txt_cusername.Text <> reader("Username").ToString Then
            If reader("SourceTable").ToString = "A" then
               frm_2custhome.Show()
            Else
               frm_SomeOtherForm.Show()
            End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Sandra, but I still cannot get it to work. I cant post my code in here but I cannot word my SQL Statement like your example above because it is in a string. I will post it in another comment.

Comment: Dim SelectStmt As String = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'JKP' AS SourceTable, ID, Username, Password FROM [AJkpLogIn] UNION SELECT 'Clarke' AS SourceTable, ID, Username, Password FROM [AClarkeLogIn]) AS CombinedTables WHERE Username= '" & txt_husername.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS AND Password= '" & txt_hpassword.Text & "' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS"

Comment: Are you receiving an error when the code is executed - if so, what is the error?  --I included the actual T-SQL as I've found it helpful to first verify the SQL statement works before including it in the code, which is what I did with the SQL stmt here.

Comment: No there is specific error; when debugged it doesn't do anything? I think its because of the way I have structured my SQL Statement?

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't retrieve any records?  You might try setting a breakpoint immediately after the `SelectStmt` is constructed, copy its contents and try executing it in Sql Mgmt Studio.  Verify the username and password combo exists and there are no embedded single-quotes in them (if there are, you'll need to modify the fields before they're inserted in your `SelectStmt` contents).